# Not getting mail in Inbox

Tags: android, jakarta-mail

My Code

```
class AsyncCalls extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {   
            EmailSendActivity sender = new EmailSendActivity("abc@gmail.com", "abc@123");
            sender.sendMail("This is Subject",   
                    "This is Body",   
                    "abc@gmail.com",   
                    "xyz@gmail.com");   
            Log.d("hhh","mail sent");
        } catch (Exception e) {   
            Log.e("SendMail", e.getMessage(), e);   
        } 
        return null;
    }

}
```

MY EmailSendActivity

```
package com.clip.android;
import javax.activation.DataHandler;   
import javax.activation.DataSource;   
import javax.mail.Message;   
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;   
import javax.mail.Session;   
import javax.mail.Transport;   
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;   
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;   
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;   
import java.io.IOException;   
import java.io.InputStream;   
import java.io.OutputStream;   
import java.security.Security;   
import java.util.Properties;   

public class EmailSendActivity extends javax.mail.Authenticator {   
    private String mailhost = "smtp.gmail.com";   
    private String user;   
    private String password;   
    private Session session;   

    static {   
        Security.addProvider(new com.clip.android.JSSEProvider());   
    }  

    public EmailSendActivity(String user, String password) {   
        this.user = user;   
        this.password = password;   

        Properties props = new Properties();   
        props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");   
        props.setProperty("mail.host", mailhost);   
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");   
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");   
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");   
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",   
                "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");   
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");   
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.quitwait", "false");   

        session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, this);   
    }   

    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {   
        return new PasswordAuthentication(user, password);   
    }   

    public synchronized void sendMail(String subject, String body, String sender, String recipients) throws Exception {   
        try{
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);   
        DataHandler handler = new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(body.getBytes(), "text/plain"));   
        message.setSender(new InternetAddress(sender));   
        message.setSubject(subject);   
        message.setDataHandler(handler);   
        if (recipients.indexOf(',') > 0)   
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(recipients));   
        else  
            message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipients));   
        Transport.send(message);   
        }catch(Exception e){

        }
    }   

    public class ByteArrayDataSource implements DataSource {   
        private byte[] data;   
        private String type;   

        public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data, String type) {   
            super();   
            this.data = data;   
            this.type = type;   
        }   

        public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data) {   
            super();   
            this.data = data;   
        }   

        public void setType(String type) {   
            this.type = type;   
        }   

        public String getContentType() {   
            if (type == null)   
                return "application/octet-stream";   
            else  
                return type;   
        }   

        public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {   
            return new ByteArrayInputStream(data);   
        }   

        public String getName() {   
            return "ByteArrayDataSource";   
        }   

        public OutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {   
            throw new IOException("Not Supported");   
        }   
    }   
}
```

My JSSEProvider

```
import java.security.AccessController;
import java.security.Provider;

public final class JSSEProvider extends Provider {

    public JSSEProvider() {
        super("HarmonyJSSE", 1.0, "Harmony JSSE Provider");
        AccessController.doPrivileged(new java.security.PrivilegedAction<Void>() {
            public Void run() {
                put("SSLContext.TLS",
                        "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.SSLContextImpl");
                put("Alg.Alias.SSLContext.TLSv1", "TLS");
                put("KeyManagerFactory.X509",
                        "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.KeyManagerFactoryImpl");
                put("TrustManagerFactory.X509",
                        "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.TrustManagerFactoryImpl");
                return null;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

LOGCAT

> 05-23 08:07:04.439: D/dalvikvm(2181): threadid=11: still suspended
>   after undo (sc=1 dc=1)
>
> 05-23 08:07:04.449: D/dalvikvm(2181): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1863K, 15%
>   free 14812K/17304K, paused 9ms, total 12ms 05-23 08:07:12.549:
>   D/dalvikvm(2181): threadid=11: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1)
>
> 05-23 08:07:12.549: D/dalvikvm(2181): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1832K, 15%
>   free 14807K/17304K, paused 13ms, total 16ms
>
> 05-23 08:07:28.660: D/dalvikvm(2181): threadid=11: still suspended
>   after undo (sc=1 dc=1)
>
> 05-23 08:07:28.670: D/dalvikvm(2181): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1828K, 15%
>   free 14811K/17304K, paused 0ms, total 13ms
>
> 05-23 08:07:36.760: D/dalvikvm(2181): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1843K, 15%
>   free 14810K/17304K, paused 8ms, total 10ms
>
> 05-23 08:07:42.760: D/hhh(2181): mail sent

I'm Not Getting error ...But I'm not getting any mail to my in Inbox...
I even declared Internet permission in Manifest..I even have all 3 jars with license of apache also... Please help me to resolve this

Comment: check your sender/receiver mail-id is correct or not. print your exception trace

Comment: You should try to print the exception that you are catching in sendMail

Comment: I had checked sender n receiver mail-Id's and password

Comment: Just because your logs say "mail sent" doesn't mean there wasn't an exception in the sendMail method

Comment: check your drafts folder and sent folder. It will give you an idea about whether mail was tried to sent and if it was really sent.

Comment: No i didn't seen my mail in draft or in sent folder

Comment: check in spam folder. May be mail recognize it as spam.

Comment: I hope you don't need the JSSEProvider.  You definitely don't need ByteArrayDataSource since it [comes with JavaMail](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/util/ByteArrayDataSource.html).  You [don't need the socket factory settings](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).  Hopefully you're using the [JavaMail for Android](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home#JavaMail_for_Android) release.  If none of that fixes your problem, post the [JavaMail debug output](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug).